# How do I get a "click" from a FrameLayout in a custom ActionBar?

Tags: android, onclick, android-actionbar, nosuchmethoderror

I have a FrameLayout defined in xml with:

```
android:onClick="cancel"
```

The activity that creates the ActionBar has a method that looks like:

```
public void cancel ( View view ) {
// Do stuff
}
```

However, when I click the "button", I get: *could not find a method cancel(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler...*

...what gives?

Comment: By default, a FrameLayout is not clickable. Thus, onClick attribute will not trigger unless you add clickable="true" attribute to the FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is how it's done:

```
    FrameLayout cancelButton = ( FrameLayout ) actionBar.getCustomView ().findViewById ( R.id.actionbar_cancel );

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener ( new OnClickListener () {

        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v ) {
            // DO STUFF
        }
    } );
```